# Juniper SRX routing based on Network

Tags: routing, juniper, srx

So, a Juniper SRX 220 in a shared use building. Two networks, 192.168.30.0/24 (The shared use) and 192.168.31.0/24 (the private network). We had once cable modem, and it currently allows only the 31.0 network across a VPN to corporate. Now they put in a Point to Point Fiber, and we need to send all traffic on the 31.0 across the P2P, and all 30.0 across the Cable modem. GE0/0 - Cable GE0/1 - LAN GE0/2 - Fiber P2P

Currently, the default route is to 0/0, and traffic for corporate across the VPN st.0

Since they now want all traffic on the 31.0 (including Internet bound traffic) to go across the VPN to the main office for tracking purposes, I will need to change the default route for the 31.0 network, while leaving the 30.0 network default route the 0/1 default gateway.

I have not been able to find anything to help me do this, thoughts on how to proceed?

Wrongly posted this over on ServerFault, so apologize for the cross post since I couldn't move the question.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the configuration guide?  Look at this page: http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos14.2/topics/example/routing-protocol-static-security-basic-set-of-route-configuring-cli.html

Comment: You can use a couple of different methods, to achieve your goal. You could put each network in a VRF, where you would specify a default route or you could use Filter-based forwarding.

Comment: you could resolve this by using policy to send the traffic to the VPN

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/example/firewall-filter-option-filter-based-forwarding-example.html

This would explain how to decide how to route by origin.
But I'd prefer - like Indigo said - to use virtual-routers on the srx.

Just configure a routing-instance for each network, add the interfaces to the routing instances and set the routing per instance like you wish. 
You don't need to build 2 instances, you can use the master instance, too.

Kind regards,
Flo